# Select column if not NULL then select other

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to figure how to return a row with the associated value when using the JOIN syntax, firstly it should check the `links` table to see if the row is `NULL`, if it's not `NULL` use that for the `JOIN` e.g. `ON links.role_id = roles.role_id` if the row is `NULl`. If it's `NULL` then use the `people` table.

My syntax:

```
SELECT roles.role_name
FROM
(
    people_links links

    LEFT OUTER JOIN people people ON links.person_id = people.person_id

    LEFT OUTER JOIN roles roles ON links.role_id = roles.role_id OR links.role_id = people.role_id
)
```

Basically when joining and using the `ON` syntax with the `role_id`, it will return the associated value from the `roles` table that is used from the `role_id` so it should rely on the `links` table **first**, check if `links.role_id` is `NULL` then return `people.role_id` else `links.role_id` for the `JOIN` to get the `role_name`.

When I run this query, it uses the `role_id` from the `people` table first, when it should look in the `links` table first.

I tried using `COALESCE` but that will only return the `role_id` when it should return `role_name`, so for example (pseudo code):

```
SELECT IF(links.role_id IS NOT NULL) links.role_id ELSE people.role_id ENDIF as join_value
FROM
(
    people_links links

    LEFT OUTER JOIN people people ON links.person_id = people.person_id

    LEFT OUTER JOIN roles roles ON roles.role_id = join_value
)
```

Comment: Actually, despite my answer below -- I now think that I don't understand what you're trying to do. Could you show some sample data, with expected results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could* write `IF(links.role_id IS NOT NULL, links.role_id, people.role_id)` — that's the closest thing to your pseudocode — but it's more idiomatic to write `COALESCE(links.role_id, people.role_id)`.

For information on `IF`, see [§11.4 "Control Flow Functions" in the MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html); for information on `COALESCE`, see [§11.3.2 "Comparison Functions and Operators"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think for code clarity that I would have two joins onto role. One from the link to role and one from the people to role. I.e.

```
SELECT
COALESCE(links_roles.role_name, people_roles.role_name)
FROM
(
    people_links links

    LEFT OUTER JOIN people people ON links.person_id = people.person_id

    LEFT OUTER JOIN roles link_roles ON links.role_id = link_roles.role_id

    LEFT OUTER JOIN roles people_roles ON people.role_id = people_roles.role_id
)
```